# Expected a value of type 'List', but got one of type '_JsonMap'

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

i'm new at flutter and i trying to call Django api and catch data from Django endpoint but keep getting this error ' Expected a value of type 'List', but got one of type '_JsonMap' '
so here is my UserAPI class :

```
class UserAPI{

  int user;
  String rank;
  UserAPI({required this.user,required this.rank});

  factory UserAPI.fromJson(Map<String,dynamic> json){
    return UserAPI(user: json['user'], rank: json['rank']);
  }



}
```

and my statefull widget:

```
class AllUser extends StatefulWidget {
  const AllUser({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<AllUser> createState() => _AllUserState();
}

class _AllUserState extends State<AllUser> {
  late Future<List<UserAPI>> futureUsers;
  final url= 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/users/all-users';
  Future<List<UserAPI>> fetchUserAPI() async{

   http.Response  response =  await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
  List users = json.decode(response.body);


  return users.map((user)=>UserAPI.fromJson(user)).toList();
  }

  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
        futureUsers = fetchUserAPI();
  }

.
.
.
```

if you can help me i'll be very grateful

Comment: and this is my response :
[
    {
        "user": 2,
        "rank": "PLATINUM",


    },
    {
        "user": 1,
        "rank": "CHALLENGER",


    }
]

Comment: I have check and nothing wrong with your code, maybe your response in comment wrong, i see it has end comma, which not valid json format type

Comment: @manhtuan21
 Thanks for your comments my full JSON response is  `{
        "user": 2,
        "rank": "PLATINUM",
        "game_won": 9,
        "time_played": 10
    }, `but i just want user and rank field so i deleted before post it here

Comment: @pskink this List will convert to ListView and thats when i get error

Comment: What do you see if you `print(response.body)`?

Comment: @pskink thank you for your help its was Authentication credentials problem from Django backend and i changed it so its work fine now